# default number system and charecter set in java

Tags: java, utf-8, binary

Thi is a fundamental questuion about how java works and so i dont have any code to support it.

I am new to java development and want to know how the different number systems, charecter sets like UTF 8 and unicode come together in Java.

Lets say a user creates a new string and int with the same value.

```
int i=100;
String S="100";
```

The hardware of a computer understands zeros and ones. so it has to be converted to binary?(correct me if im wrong). this conversion should be done by the JVM(correct me if im wrong)? and to represent charecters of different languages into charecters that can be typed into the keyboard (english) UTF-8 and such conversions are used(correction needed)?

now how does this whole flow fit into the bigger picture of running a java web application?

how does a string/int get converted to a binary for the machine's hardware to understand?
how does it get converted to UTF-8 for a browser to understand? 
and what are the default number format and charecterset in java? if im reading contents of a file? will they be read into binary or utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

All computers run in binary. The conversion is done by the JVM and the computer that you have. You shouldn't worry about converting the code into the coordinating 1's and 0's. The browser has its own conversion hard code to change the universal 1's and 0's(used by all programs and computer software) into however it decides to display the given information. All languages are just a translation guide for the user to "speak" with the computer. And vice versa. Hope this helps though I don't think I really answered anything.

Comment: ur right.. u said the question again without sounding like a question. but i appreciate the interest :) 
if i enter my user name and password in a web page.. it finally translates to binary and returns as string. there are three actors here performing the translation
hardware, jvm, browser  who does what in the conversion?

Comment: Ah, I understand the question now. So, the browser is only a data "bus" if you will. A host for the JVM to communicate with. The user input is sent directly into the JVM to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

How java represents *any* data type in memory is *the choice of the actual JVM*. In practice, the JVM will chose the format native to the processor (e.g. chose between little/big endian for int), simply because it offers the best performance on that platform.

Basically, the JLS makes certain guarantees (like that a byte has 8 bits and the values range from -128 to 127) - the VM just maps that to the platform as it deems suitable (the JLS was specified to match common computing technology closely, so there is usually no magic needed to guess how primitive types map to the platform).

You should never care how the VM represents data in memory, java does not offer *any legal* way to access the data in a manner where you would need to know (bypassing most of the VM's logic by using sun.misc.Unsafe is not considered *legal*).
If you care for educational purposes, learn what binary representations the underlying platform (e.g. x86) uses and take a look at the VM. It has little to do with java really, its all VM and platform specific.

For java.lang.String, its the implementation of the class that defines how the String is stored internally - it went through quite some changes over major java versions - but what that String exposes is quite narrowly defined (see JDK javadoc for String.length(), String.charAt()).

As for how user input is translated to java standard types, thats actually platform specific. The JVM selects the default encoding (e.g. String.toBytes() can return quite different results for the same string, depending on the platform - thats why its recommended to explictly specify the desired encoding). Same goes for many other things (time zone, number format etc.).

CharSets and Formats are building blocks the program wires up to translate data from the outside world (file, http or user input) into javas representation of data (or vice versa). For example, a Web application will use the encoding from a HTTP header to determine what CharSet to use when interpreting the contents (the HTTP headers encoding is defined to be US-ASCII by the spec).

Comment: so to summarize.                                                          Java will read the user input int i=0; which is encoded into different standards ---->> jvm will map this to a 32bit/4byte memory---->>platform/OS will translate it into binary in such a way that the underlying X86/X64 processor understands??                                am i right?